# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/MQException in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ibm-mq

I am running a dynamic web project, but am encountering the following errors from Tomcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/MQException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.MQException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 20 more
```

I have the com.ibm.mq.jar added as an external jar. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Where did you _added as an external jar_?

Comment: Adding as external jar will make that jar available for compile time. One way is, copy that jar to your project lib folder.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In the Java Build Path section in project properties.

Comment: @Nambari Which lib folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark that jar as needing to be deployed from your project's Deployment Assembly property page.  By default, only the jars physically in the WEB-INF/lib folder will be deployed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need more than just ***com.ibm.mq.jar*** file to connect to a remote queue manager.

If you are using WMQ v6.0 or lower then you need the following MQ JAR files:

- com.ibm.mq.jar
- connector.jar

If you are using WMQ v7.0, v7.1, v7.5 or higher then you need the following MQ JAR files:

- com.ibm.mq.jar
- connector.jar
- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar

If you are using JMS in your application then you also need:

- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- jms.jar

Are you using MQ JNDI?  If so, also add the jndi.jar file too.

This is the standard RTM, as it is well documented.